# Empty List Python during List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to find if there is a number (other than 2017) whose positive divisors sum to 2018.
Here is my Python 3 code. I can do it the first way, but wanted to try with list comprehensions. But the list is empty when I run it.

```
import math

def divisors(x):
  divisors = []
  for y in range(1,math.floor(x*0.5)+1):
    if x%y==0:
      divisors.append(y)
  divisors.append(x)
  return divisors

for x in range(2018):
  if sum(divisors(x)) == 2018:
    print(x,sum(divisors(x)))

print([x for x in range(1,2018) if (sum(divisors(x)))==0])
```

Also, any other tips for simplifying code or increasing efficiency will be appreciated!

Comment: Your `for` loop tests for `== 2018`, your list comprehension tests for `== 0`. That's a very different test.

Comment: Seems like you need `(sum(divisors(x)))==2018` in list-comprehension?

Comment: whoops, Thanks! Can any simplifying be done?

Comment: If a list comprehension does not seem to work, write it out as a proper loop so you can debug it. I prefer to do this the other way around: I start with an explicit loop and only then check if making it a list comprehension makes sense.

Comment: Yes, there are faster ways to find all the divisors of a number and to compute their sum. FWIW, the only number < 1000000 whose divisors sum to 2018 is 2017. I'm pretty sure there are no other solutions. See https://www.quora.com/The-sum-of-the-factors-of-a-natural-number-is-124-What-is-the-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if sum of divisors is equal to 2018 instead of 0

```
import math

def divisors(x):
  divisors = []
  for y in range(1,math.floor(x*0.5)+1):
    if x%y==0:
      divisors.append(y)
  divisors.append(x)
  return divisors

for x in range(2018):
  if sum(divisors(x)) == 2018:
    print(x,sum(divisors(x)))

print([x for x in range(1,2018) if (sum(divisors(x)))==2018])
```